# Estimate the probability using Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

please consider this question:

> A study using Markov chains to estimate a patient's prognosis for
>   improving under various treatment plans gives the following transition
>   matrix as an example
>
> [image]
>
> a) Estimate the probability that a well person will eventually end up
>   dead.
>
> b) Find the expected number of cycles that a well patient will continue
>   to be well before dying, and the expected number of cycles that a well
>   patient will be ill before dying.

Sorry I'm new to Markov chains and please help me solve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the guy starts out healthy. You need to construct a recurrent equation for the 3-state MC with 1 absorbing state:
$$
h_{1,3}=0.3 h_{1,3} +0.5 h_{2,3} +0.2 h_{3,3}\\
h_{2,3}=0.5 h_{2,3}+0.5 h_{3,3}
$$
Keep in mind $h_{3,3}=1$ (obviously). Solve for $h_{1,3}$. For the second problems use Geometric probability.

Comment: Thanks dear Alex.I use you approach and $$h_1,3 = 1 $$. but Can you please help me for second problem.thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Geometric distribution?

Comment: To solve (1) you can also use the fact there's a finite number of states, one of the states is absorbing and hence forms a separate communicating class